how do i remove noise from a wav file using matlab?
ive been trying using a code i found online but i cant seem to find the right filtering parameters since i have no idea what im doing anyway lol
here are the noisy and noiseless files: https://file.io/lO9dGsWQJFZR
code i found:
% Read the noisy and noiseless audio files
noisy_audio = audioread('noisy.wav');
noiseless_audio = audioread('original.wav');

% Define Butterworth filter parameters
order = 2; % Filter order
fc = 300; % Cutoff frequency in Hz

% Design the Butterworth filter
[b, a] = butter(order, fc/(8000/2), 'low');

% Filter the noisy audio
filtered_audio = filter(b, a, noisy_audio);

% Plotting
t = (0:length(noisy_audio)-1)/8000;

% Plot the waveforms
figure;
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t, noisy_audio);
title('Noisy Audio');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t, noiseless_audio);
title('Noiseless Audio');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t, filtered_audio);
title('Filtered Audio');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

% Play the filtered audio
sound(filtered_audio, 8000);


plots:
plot

Using a Butterworth Filter would be a good start. This code looks like it's creating a feedback loop to create a filter. So my question to you is: How much do you know about signal processing? And if you don't have to use a filter, why not make a simple if...else statement where if a particular frequency is above a certain amount, then make it zero?

i actually have little knowledge about signal processing and the things is we were tasked to design a filter. i think this code will do if i just picked the right order and cut off frequency, idk pls correct me if im wrong thanks
